# Regular Expression Replace in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

```
Test 1
Test & Test 2
Test,Test 2
Test-Test2
Test/Test2
Test. Test2
Test 1 Test 2 Test 3
Test 1 Test 2 - Test 3, Test 4, Test 5
```

I have the following string array, I need to replace this via javascript regex to convert all of these to lowercase and separated with `-`.

Expected output

```
test-1
test-test-2
test-test2
```

I have been using this till now

```
link = str.replace(new RegExp("[^a-zA-Z0-9-]", "gi"), "-").toLowerCase();
link = link.replace("--", "-");
```

Comment: Try adding `\n` in your character class `[^a-zA-Z0-9\n-]`

Comment: The last line of the expected output shouldn't have a `-` before the `2`? Is that correct? If so, how are you distinguishing it from the first line?

Comment: I mentioned these are separate strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would remove the `-` from the regex, and add the `+` to describe one or more of the characters to be replaced.

```
var str = "Test 1 Test 2 - Test 3, Test 4, Test 5"
var regex = new RegExp("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", "gi");

str.replace(regex, "-").toLowerCase(); // "test-1-test-2-test-3-test-4-test-5"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.toLowerCase` and this regexp: `/[^a-z0-9-]+/g`

```
'Test & Test 2'.toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z0-9-]+/g, '-')
#=> 'test-test-2'
```

`+` will match 1 or more occurrences, so it'll replace all consecutive characters, and replace them with a single `-`